# Target Lower API Level than Package or Plug-In Requirements

Tags: unity, c#, android

I am working on a project that I want to use local mobile notifications for Android using Unity as game engine. I want to reach as much as users I can, so I want to target API level 16 for the lowest Android API level. As expected, when targeting Android API level 16 for a build, build fails with that error:

> Execution failed for task ':processReleaseManifest'.  
>  Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library [:androidnotifications-release:] C:\Users\Tumay Varel.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\71d39d4badfde5815e850866bcf079c9\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
>        
> Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
>            
> or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 19,
>            
> or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.unity.androidnotifications" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

In [documentation](https://diy.stackexchange.com) , it is explicitly saying that the package supports Android 4.4 (API 19) and higher API levels. I can handle this problem by targeting lowest API level 19, however I want to ask: Is there a way to use this package or any other package or any plug-in  for required and higher API levels while not using for lower API levels than requirement at the same project?

Comment: It sounds like you might be asking about a custom build script that checks whether you're building your level 16-18 version or your 19+ version, and modifies your project on the fly to remove incompatible dependencies before proceeding with compilation, then puts it back afterward so you can still build your level 19+ version in a second pass. Does that match what you need?

Comment: Yes, that solution matches exactly what I want. Can I do that with custom build scripts?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it could be a fruitful angle to research!

Comment: I will look at it, thanks a lot.